# jmeter logger format change

Tags: logging, jmeter

Jmeter logger has the date format as yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss

I wanted to change the format and add milliseconds and timezone offset to it(yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss.SSSZ) as well. Is there a way to format this date format?

Answer (score 0):

JMeter uses Avalon logging with the default format of:

```
log_format=%{time:yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss} %5.5{priority} - %{category}: %{message} %{throwable}
```

Check out [PatternFormatter](http://excalibur.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/log/format/PatternFormatter.html) documentation to learn how to amend timestamps according to your requirement and put the updated line in *user.properties* file (lives in /bin folder of your JMeter installation).

JMeter restart will be required to pick the property up.

See [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization) for additional information on JMeter properties types and ways of working with them.

Answer (score -1):

- For timestamp in the results .jtl files, Set this property:

  jmeter.save.saveservice.timestamp_format=yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss.SSSZ

either as a `-D` java opt at startup, or in JMeter `bin/saveservice.properties`

- For timestamp in `jmeter.log`

  log_format=%{time:yyyy/MM/dd hh:mm:ss.SSSZ} %5.5{priority} - %{category}: %{message} %{throwable}

in `user.properties`

- You can also generate a `root.log` by editing `log4j.conf` in jmeter/bin folder. The log4j pattern contains a timestamp pattern.